# How grant access to remote mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

i have installed mysql on ubuntu server, but i want to connect with mysql workbench remotely.
I just see other answer, but my /etc/mysql/my.cnf is that:

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3           File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf                    Modified  

# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I just Grant privileges to 'root'@'%'

This is netstat:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16431/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1471/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      15874/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1471/sshd

What can i do? Any ideas of bad configuration?

Comment: You need to make sure that the lines containing "skip-networking" and "bind-address = " are commented out.  Edit:  in the my.cnf

Comment: The file doesnt has that line, i wrote in the question. There are only two include.

Comment: Then it's probably in either /etc/mysql/conf.d/some-file-here.

Comment: i use ssh connection instead of tcp-ip, i resolved my problem.